# Set selected index of dropdown to zero after form submit in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a bit new to ASP.NET MVC. I have created the below dropdown using HTML  helpers in ASP.NET MVC 5. When I submit the form I want to set the selected index to zero. Here I am using an option label "--select--". I want to set the selected value to that one ("--select--") after submitting. How do I achieve this?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestCategory, new SelectList(@ViewBag.TestCategories, "value", "text"), "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control input-sm"})
```

**Controller Code**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new LaboratoryViewModel { 
            medicaltestlist = new List<MedicalTest>()
        };
        PopTestCategory();
        PopEmptyDropdown();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LaboratoryViewModel labvm)
    {
        var test = PopMedicalTests().Where(x => x.TestSerial == Convert.ToInt32(labvm.TestCode)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (labvm.medicaltestlist == null)
            labvm.medicaltestlist = new List<MedicalTest>();
        if(!labvm.medicaltestlist.Any(x=> x.TestSerial == test.TestSerial))
            labvm.medicaltestlist.Add(test);
        labvm.TestCategory = "";
        PopTestCategory();
        return View(labvm);
    }

    public void PopTestCategory()
    {
        var categorylist = new List<DropDownItem>
        {
            new DropDownItem{value="Medical",text="Medical"},
            new DropDownItem{value="Animal",text="Animal"},
            new DropDownItem{value="Food",text="Food"},
            new DropDownItem{value="Water",text="Water"}
        };
        ViewBag.TestCategories = categorylist;
    }

    public class DropDownItem
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: DropDownListhas a relationship with TestCategory property Model, so if you set this property to null or empty after a submit and return the model to the view

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: can you show your controller code ?

Comment: @DanielVorph I updated the above code

Comment: the view have more fileds. I have set the value and resend them to the view. `labvm.TestCategory = "";`

Comment: what is DropDownItem namespace?

Comment: @HaseebAsif it is a class that i have created. Check , i updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the view in you post method so if you selected (say) `Animal` then that value will be selected when you return the view because the html helpers use the values from `ModelState`, not the model property. Setting `labvm.TestCategory = "";` has no effect. The correct approach is to follow the PRG pattern and redirect to the GET method, however you can make this work by calling `ModelState.Clear();` before setting resetting the value of `TestCategory` although this will clear all `ModelState` properties and errors and may have other side effects.

Side note: You `DropDownItem` class seems unnecessary. MVC already has a `SelectListItem` class designed to work with dropdownlists, and in any case you can replace all the code in your `PopEmptyDropdown()` method with

```
ViewBag.TestCategories = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Medical", "Animal", "Food", "Water" });
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TestCategory, (SelectList)@ViewBag.TestCategories, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control input-sm"})
```

Comment: I am still getting familiar with these things gradually.. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the "value" attribute of the top item in the drop down list to something and then pass back a model containing that for the bound property it should work?